# TNS listener could not find available handler with matching protocol stack?

Tags: java, oracle, glassfish, tns

i have an web app in jsf + glassfish + oracleDB 10g

this is a random error, in my pc the app works fine, doesn't show this error page, 
but for others few pc the error page comes

I clean the cookies for that pc, but it doesn't works, when i put f5 to refresh the page
sometimes reload the page without the error page.

in my DB the numbers of process/session are 60 of 180 permit.
I use jdbc (classes12.jar) to connect to the database like this

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
connection= DriverManager.getConnection(DBURL, user, pass);
```

any ideas of this?

[image]

Comment: Instead of the naive way i.e.`Class.forName(<...>);`, use a database connection pool.

Comment: could you be more specific or send me a link to read more about this please?

Comment: in my glassfish my connection pool is like this "org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDataSource" but in my java is "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" ... should be both the same ??